# Failing to load image in ImageView for the 7" tab device layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I am trying to put a background image in a imageview for the sw600dp layout file, but its not getting loaded where as same is getting loaded on other layout whose density is less than 600dp.
The image is put in the drawable folder.
I am not getting whats may be the problem. Below is the code for sw600dp layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="stvisionary.fashionove.com.Activity.StartActivity">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/backImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/start_image"
    android:scaleType="center"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try adding `android:largeHeap="true"` in you `application` tag in manifest file

Comment: put some code or you can use picasso or universal image loader

Comment: post your sw600dp layout code.

Comment: @ArunShankar i have put the code for the layout-sw600dp

Comment: @Rustam - i have put the largeHead tag, but its not working

Comment: at least use correctly formated keys: android:ScaleType -> android:scaleType (But I assume this will not solve your problem). largeHeap won't work if you are using exactly the same image for both.

Comment: @VizGhar that was a typing mistake, yeah I m using the same image.
Please give me any solution .

Comment: Try to set image programmatically: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource%28int%29 (use it only for debug purposes) place breakpoints before and after using this method and see Logs between those 2 you may be a little bit more aware of what is going on there. Is there anything you can read from log?

Comment: btw can you see the image in layout preview for both resolution? Double check your resources because i cant see any problem with your layout file